# Multiple items passed into Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem. When publishing with clickOnce

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, clickonce

Create a desktop application, and I generate the installer correctly, but when I copy the project to another computer to generate the installer, I get the following error:
App.config; obj \ Debug .... csproj.projectname.exe.config is an invalid value for the ConfigFile parameter of the GenerateApplicationManifest task "You can not pass multiple elements in a parameter of type" Microsoft.Build.Frameworkk. ITaskItem "

[image]

Check that to solve it you had to remove the following line of code from the .csproj file:

I did it, but now it tells me the following error:

Error 1 Error connecting with '\ localhost \ Users \ UserName \ Desktop \ Deploy \'. The following error appears:

> The website '\ localhost \ Users \ OpenCode \ Desktop \ Deploy' can
>   not be created. The path '\ localhost \ Users \ OpenCode \ Desktop \
>   Deploy' does not exist or does not have access to it. The specified
>   path is not valid.

It is very strange, check, according to the correct route, the only thing that changes in the route is the name of `C: \ by localhost`., Since in the previous computer, where the installer generated it, it did it correctly.

If anyone has any ideas, thank you. Greetings.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue with Windows service, It happened when I migrated the project from  `.Net Framework 4.5` to `.Net Framework 4.7.2`, You just have to make below changes in your project file (`.csproj`)

Change below line

```
<AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="app.config" />
```

to

```
<AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="@(AppConfigWithTargetPath)"/>
```

Comment: Happened to me when I activated "Auto-generate binding redirects" in the project settings, this looks like the right way to fix it.